# v-for components don't update in real time

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a parent component `Data` which fetches state from Vuex, I use that state to generate some child components `Table` to which I pass some of that Vuex data as props, all of this inside a `v-for`.

```
<template>
  <table v-for="(item,index) in data"
  :key="index + item.id"
  :propX="item.x"
  :propY="item.y"
  />
</template>
<script>
  name: "Data",
  components: {
   Table
  },
  computed:{
    data(){
    return this.$store.state.data;  
   }
  }
</script>
```

My `Table` components also mutate the Vuex state, and I can see the state mutates just fine inside the `Data` component (vue dev tools), but the Data component doesn't update the props of my `Table` components.

Comment: it's recommend to not use the reserved html element names like `table`, try `MyTable` and in template `my-table`

Comment: [vue 2 list problem](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)? If it is, you can see it.

Comment: I had a similar problem, where the props of a child only get updated, if they are used to be rendered in the component, or are part of a computed value that is rendered in the component. Could you provide Component Code?

Comment: on the other hand: Why not only pass a static field (e.g.: item.id) to the component via props, and have it fetch itself the data from the store for the given id. That way you don't rely on the parent to pass down state-changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

several issues here:

1. Do not use reserved names for components and computed values (do not use `table`)
2. Be aware that if your state is array of objects or nested object it might not be reactive. You have to re-assign the object/array or use `set` method for it to be reactive.

some examples

```
// update objects
this.$set(this.$store.state.data, 'a', 1)
Vue.set(this.$store.state.data, 'a', 1)
this.$store.state.data = Object.assign({}, oldObject, { a: 1 })

//update array of objects
this.$store.state.data = [...data, newObject]
```